# How to put a button active by default?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

thanks in advance.

The question is:

I have 2 buttons that shows the content of the div when the user click on it.

The content of the div are in a function that shows the content when the users click on the button (onclick).

But when the page loads just appear the two buttons without any content, is there any way to 'put' one of these buttons as active by default?

I tried with this:

Html:

```
<div class="diferencias col-md-12 col-lg-12">
 <div class="diferencias col-md-6 col-lg-6"><input type="button" value="Web" onClick="fashioncatweb();">
</div>
 <div class="diferencias col-md-6 col-lg-6"> <input type="button" value="Logo" onClick="fashioncatlogo();">
</div>
 </div>

<div class="row">
<div id="container">
<div id="content"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function fashioncatweb()
{
var text = "<p>text";
var img = "images/.....";
var content = "<div class=\"col-md-7\"><div class=img><img class=img-responsive src=\"" + img + "\" alt=\"\" /></div></div>"
   + "<div class=\"col-md-5\"><div class=pre-scrollable id=\"fashion\">" + text + "</div></div>";
appendToContainer(content);
}

function fashioncatlogo()
{
var text = "<p>text";
var img = "images/....png";
var content = "<div class=\"col-md-7\"><div class=img><img class=img-responsive src=\"" + img + "\" alt=\"logo\" /></div></div>"
+ "<div class=\"col-md-5\"><div class=pre-scrollable id=\"logo\">" + text + "</div></div>";
appendToContainer(content); 
}


$(document).ready(function () {
  piramidalweb();
});
```

But it just works for one section and I have like 15 different sections.

Thanks again!!

Comment: Is there any way to 'put' your code? Otherwise we can't help you.

Comment: Does the button tag has hidden attribute set.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a function that is called on the click of the buttons:

Using pure Javascript:

```
<input type="button" value="Button1" id="btn1" onclick="showContent(this.id)" />

function showContent(id) {
  if(id === "btn1") {
      // show the content 
  }
}
```

Then call immediately at the base of the page within script tags:

```
showContent("btn1");
```

That will load the content immediately.

To improve this you would execute this function onload, or in a ready function within jQuery, but hopefully you'll be able to take it from there.

Comment: thanks for you help, I tried this code but is not working :/ do you have another idea? thanks-!

Comment: If you implemented it correctly that code would work. I see you've updated your question though. Put fashioncatweb() in the ready(). If that doesn't work you have a bug elsewhere. Look in the developer tools console window of your browser.

Comment: And if you have 15 of those functions you should look into DRY (don't repeat yourself) principles - there is a lot of duplication of code. See the fashioncatweb and fashioncatlogi do the same thing with different logo and content.